# Numpy: multiply first elements n elements along an axis where n is given by an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3D numpy array, e.g. `A = np.random.rand(a, b, c)`, and I want to compute the product of the first `n` elements across the last axis (i.e. axis=2), where each n is given by an array `N` with `N.shape = (a, b)`. The end result is a 2d array with shape `(a, b)`.

For instance, let's say one slice (e.g. for `a=0, b=0`) is `[3, 2, 5, 7]`, and `N[0, 0] = 3`, then I want the product `3*2*5`, that is, multiply the first n=3 elements.

Is there any efficient way of doing this without resorting to very slow quasi-for-loop solitions like `np.fromiter` or `np.vectorize`?

Edit: as per request, a minimal example

```
A = np.array([
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]],
[[1, 2, 1], [3, 2, 4]]
])

N = np.array([
[2, 1],
[3, 2]
])

# desired result using a for loop:
desired_result = np.full(N.shape, np.nan)
for a in range(A.shape[0]):
    for b in range(A.shape[1]):
        # multiply the first n=N[a, b] elements
        desired_result[a, b] = np.product(A[a, b][:N[a, b]])

print(desired_result)
# output = array([[2., 4.], [2., 6.]])
```

Comment: Could you share a minimal example and expected output?

Comment: What's the range of values in `N` for your actual use-case?

Comment: @yatu: I now provided a minimal example; @Divakar: `N` does specify integer values in the range 0 - `A.shape[2]`, that is the maximum value of `N` is given by `A.shape[2]`, since you can't multiply more values than there are present along axis 2 of array A.

Comment: @monade Understood. But, my question still is - What's the range of values in N for your actual use-case?

Comment: unclear at present, but between 10 and 100

Comment: Note that in my use case, `N.shape = (100, 10000)` approximately - this is why solutions with for loops, `np.fromiter` or `np.vectorize` are too slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Here's one vectorized way leveraging [`broadcasting`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
# Mask of same shape as 3D input array and thats has True from 0th till N[a, b]]
# for each element in N.
In [22]: m = N[...,None] > np.arange(A.shape[2])

# Use it to create an array where all alements with True in mask are A,
# 1s otherwise. The idea is when prod reduced along the last axis those False
# from mask will not affect, while valid ones will be prod-reduced with proper
# values.
In [23]: np.where(m,A,1).prod(-1)
Out[23]: 
array([[2, 4],
       [2, 6]])
```

Alternatively, using [`numexpr`](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr) to leverage `multi-cores`, as we will translate the masking steps from earlier to mathematical ones -

```
In [14]: import numexpr as ne

In [15]: ne.evaluate('prod(m*A + ~m,2)')
Out[15]: 
array([[2, 4],
       [2, 6]], dtype=int64)
```

**Approach #2**

Based on [`this idea`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64148519/), here's one with `np.multiply.reduceat` -

```
s0 = np.arange(0, A.size, A.shape[2])
p = np.stack((s0, N.ravel()+s0),axis=1).ravel()
out = np.multiply.reduceat(A.ravel(), p)[::2].reshape(N.shape)
```

Comment: Super cool. I had the same idea about creating a boolean auxiliary array `m`, but I couldn't find out how to create this without for loops either. As often in these cases, `broadcasting` is the magic solution. Thank you!

Comment: @Divakar can you explain the vectorized code ? I am unable to understand.

Comment: @MSS Added comments.