# conditional summation of cells via Pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following table below. I need the code that reads the number in column A, sums the numbers from the last non-empty** A **columns creating a new column called 'sum'.

Example:

```
   A  B    C    D    E    F     sum
0  1  1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN      1
1  2  1   2    1   NaN  NaN      3
2  3  1   2    2    1   NaN      5
3  4  1  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN      4
4  5  1  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0      5
```

I do not have any ideas. Thank you in advance!

[Attaching the screen of the table as it appears distorted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22rZQ.png)

Comment: I don't understand how the `sum` values are computed from your data. Could you explain please?

Comment: What do you mean by "the last non-empty** A ** columns"?

Answer (score 1):

Remove column `A` and reorder columns in [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for get last non missing columns. Then use cumulative sum in pandas for counter and compare by `A` column in numpy broadcasting, pass to [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) and sum matched values:

```
df1 = df.drop('A', axis=1).iloc[:, ::-1]

mask = np.cumsum(df1.notna().to_numpy(), axis=1) <= df['A'].to_numpy()[:, None]
df['sum'] = df1.where(mask, 0).sum(axis=1).astype(int)
print (df)
   A  B    C    D    E    F  sum
0  1  1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    1
1  2  1  2.0  1.0  NaN  NaN    3
2  3  1  2.0  2.0  1.0  NaN    5
3  4  1  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN    4
4  5  1  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0    5
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you need to perform a sum of slices where `A` is considered as the end ?

If so, you can try this :

```
df["sum"] = [df.iloc[i, 1:end+1].sum() for i, end in enumerate(df["A"])]
```

For a vectorial approach, maybe you can use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) :

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/64144388/16120011

a_asend = df["A"].to_numpy()
ahead_a = df.iloc[:, 1:].to_numpy()

start = np.zeros(len(df))
r = np.arange(ahead_a.shape[1])
m = (r >= start[:, None]) & (r < a_asend[:, None])

df["sum"] = np.einsum("ij,ij->i", np.nan_to_num(ahead_a), m)
```

Output :

```
print(df)

   A  B    C    D    E    F  sum
0  1  1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN 1.00
1  2  1 2.00 1.00  NaN  NaN 3.00
2  3  1 2.00 2.00 1.00  NaN 5.00
3  4  1 1.00 1.00 1.00  NaN 4.00
4  5  1 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 5.00

[5 rows x 7 columns]
```